# How to make a self aware button on ipywidgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I need to write a function that is aware of which button was clicked to call it. I am using ipywidgets and jupyter notebook.

Here is some sample code:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

button1 = widgets.Button(description = 'I am button 1')
button2 = widgets.Button(description = 'I am button 2')

def self_aware(caller):
    # Some code I don't know
    pass
    
    
button1.on_click(self_aware)
button2.on_click(self_aware)

widgets.VBox([button1, button2])
```

When clicked the button 1 should be passed as an argument to the `self_aware` function.
As an example just `print('I am button 1')` or 2 should be enough

Comment: maybe `print(caller.description)`

Comment: Thank you drops, that solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the buttons description:

```
def self_aware(caller):
    print(caller.description)
```